# I have start time,end time and duration..i want to add duration in start time till end time is achieved in c#?

Tags: c#, time, range

I have start time,end time and duration.I want to add duration in start time till end time is achieved in c#?

for e.g start time is `09:00:00`

end time is `15:00:00` and duration gap is 20 minutes

I need this kind of output:

```
09:00:00-09:20:00
09:20:00-09:40:00
09:40:00-10:00:00
```

and bind this to gridview

Comment: How do you have these times and durations?  As what kinds of objects/variables?  What mechanics are you trying to use?

Comment: possible duplicate/answer? : http://stackoverflow.com/a/11605882/1734623

Comment: only start time,end time,duration is there in database..i need to bind time like this in gridview.

Comment: What project type you're using? winfroms / WPF.

Comment: i want to bind gridview like this

Comment: So is it impossible to edit former question to include this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `TimeSpan`s, you can do:

```
TimeSpan startTime = new TimeSpan(0, 9, 0, 0);
TimeSpan endTime = new TimeSpan(0, 15, 0, 0);
TimeSpan counter = startTime;
TimeSpan durationPeriod = new TimeSpan(0, 20, 0);
List<string> durations = new List<string>();

while (counter < endTime)
{
    durations.Add(counter.ToString() + "-" + counter.Add(durationPeriod));
    counter = counter.Add(durationPeriod);
}

foreach (var duration in durations)
{
    Console.WriteLine(duration + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Output:

[image: timespan]

Answer (score 4):

This method would do that:

```
static IEnumerable<DateTime> Spend(DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime, TimeSpan duration)
{
    while (startTime <= endTime)
    {
        yield return startTime;
        startTime = startTime.Add(duration);
    }
}
```

And sample usage would be:

```
foreach (var time in Spend(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddHours(5), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20)))
    Console.WriteLine(time);
```

Comment: I would say returning IEnumerable<Tuple<DateTime,DateTime>> is clearer, as it better reflects the result is a collection of DateTime ranges.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `-` binary operator with two [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) objects, you get a [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx).

So you could do this:

```
TimeSpan t = end - start;
```

You can then add that `TimeSpan` back to a `DateTime` as many times as you want. For example, to add that interval three times to the start time:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    start = start.Add(t);
}
```

The `Add` method does not modify the `DateTime`, so that's why we assign it to the return of its method.

Now all you have to do is fetch the `DateTime`'s from the database and apply this to them.

**Edit:** I see that the interval you want to add multiple times is not the difference between the start and end times. So you could do something like this:

```
DateTime start = new DateTime(2013, 5, 29, 0, 9, 0);
DateTime end = new DateTime(2013, 5, 29, 15, 0, 0);

TimeSpan interval = new TimeSpan(0, 20, 0 0); // 20 minutes
for (DateTime temp = start; temp < end; temp = temp.Add(interval))
{
    // Here you output temp, such as:
    Console.WriteLine (temp.ToShortTimeString() + " - " + temp.Add(interval).ToShortTimeString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var startTime = new TimeSpan(9, 0, 0);
while (startTime <= new TimeSpan(15, 0, 0)) {
    var endTime = startTime + new TimeSpan(0, 20, 0);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}-{1}", startTime, endTime));
    startTime = endTime;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var dates = new List<DateTime>();

for (var dt = start; dt <= end; dt = dt.AddMinutes(gap))
{
   dates.Add(dt);
}

//  bind the gridview using dates
```